# How to make a multithreaded and async Python discord bot

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm making a discord bot, which uses some big data (500-900Mb).
My issue is that I need to refresh (getting from API) the data every minute and at the same time still answering to commands.

For it I used the discord module discordpy and its discord.ext.tasks.loop object, but as you can imagine, that's not multithreaded and the bot is terribly lagging when getting data from API.

To fix it I tried to use `asyncio.to_thread()` with `asyncio.gather()` but it doesn't works, my error is :

`RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running`.
I'm stuck with this

There is my problematic code:

```
def q():
    asyncio.run(getting_API_data)

async def main():
    print("starting gather")
    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(q),
        client.run(TOKEN)
    )
asyncio.run(main())
```

Note that `getting_API_data` is an async function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `get_API_data` is a completely asynchronous there shouldn't be an issue running both the bot and the function in the same thread. Nonetheless you can use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) and run that in another thread. Another issue is that you cannot use `client.run` here since it's a blocking function, use [`client.start`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.start) combined with [`client.close`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.close)

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def run_bot():
    try:
        await client.start()
    except Exception:
        await client.close()


def run_in_thread():
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(getting_API_data(), loop)
    fut.result()  # wait for the result


async def main():
    print("Starting gather")
    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(run_in_thread),
        run_bot()
    )


loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it helped:)

Comment: Done I guess :)