# async and threading and getting channel and sending a message to channel discord.py Python

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a feature where users get notified when its their birthday. I've been at this for weeks but can't seem to find the error.

The problem is that I keep getting an error of:

```
"Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 59, in check_for_birthdays
    await channel.send("Hey Everyone, Let's wish <@" + cord_user_id + "> Happy Birthday!!!")
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 448, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 635, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task"
```

I keep trying different things such as await asyncio.sleep(time_to_sleep) and try to get_channel() but still get errors.

The code:

```
async def check_for_birthdays(time_to_sleep):
    while True:
        from datetime import datetime
        from pytz import timezone
        tz = timezone('EST')
        obj = datetime.now(tz)
        string = str(obj).split()[1]
        index = string.index(":")
        hour = int(string[:index]) + 1

        # user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
        # user.send("hello user, some message to user")
        
        # if hour != (9):
        #     # await channel.send("checking birthdays, not 9am currently.")
        #     await asyncio.sleep(time_to_sleep)
        #     continue

        # await user.send("9am check successful.")

        lst_of_users_today = is_anyones_birthday()
        server_id = some_server_id
        guild = client.get_guild(server_id)
        channel_id = some_channel_id
        channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)

        for cord_user_id in lst_of_users_today:
            await channel.send("Hey Everyone, Let's wish <@" + cord_user_id + "> Happy Birthday!!!")
            
        time.sleep(time_to_sleep)


import asyncio
threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(check_for_birthdays(THIRTY_MINUTES*2),)).start()
```

If you have any suggestions to solve this problem another way, I'm open to suggestions. Basically, allow discord bot to run as normal without being interrupted and check on a specific hour every day if there is a birthday match, for which it shall notify them in the discord channel.

Comment: At a quick glance, this code seems very confusing. Why are you using `threading` with `asyncio`? Why import your libraries every single loop iteration?

Comment: @megargayu I'm trying for that function to run every hour but still allow my discord bot to continue with its other tasks. But yeah I just have that there temporarily, I shall change the imports to the top later.

Comment: ill look over it more later but the outstanding thing I see is that you have imports everywhere, imports should be up at the top

Comment: yep, pretty much

Comment: You shouldn't really use `asyncio.run` in a separate thread as it creates a new event loop. I answered a similar question a while ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432424/how-to-make-a-multithreaded-and-async-python-discord-bot/68432736#68432736